# Magento 2 Gallery Images HTML

Tags: magento-2.1, gallery-image

I am trying to find where in the template files I can add microdata to my products gallery images, but struggling to find the template/file that actually outputs the HTML img tags.

I am actually adding this to all relevant elements of a product detail page (description, sku, price, etc, etc, etc), however the image was the first on my list to do, and already can't locate the file!!

Can someone help point me directly to the right place?

Magento 2.1.6 using Ultimo theme.

Comment: Enable front-end template path hints and then you can easily find out your file path

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find out your template path for your gallery module,you should enable template path hints in admin panel

**---- Just for reference -----**

Step 1 : Navigate **Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront -> Yes -> Save Config**

[image]

Step 2 : Remove **Cache**

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Step 3 : Refresh storefront you can find template path for your gallery module like below screenshot(i.e just for your referrence)

[image]

**Notes : Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront -> No -> Save Config and remove cache for disabling template path hints**

Comment: Of course this is the very first thing I did, but the template that this points me to in my theme (product/view/gallery.phtml) and in the base theme does NOT include the HTML markup to insert an img tag into the page. Following the rabbit down that hole leads me to vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php which also does not create HTML tags. Where to go from there??